# Regex/algorithm in Python to extract comments from class attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, algorithm, parsing

Given the code for a class definition, I am trying to extract all attributes and their comments (`""` empty string if no comments).

```py
class Player(Schema):
    score = fields.Float()
    """
    Total points from killing zombies and finding treasures
    """

    name = fields.String()
    age = fields.Int()

    backpack = fields.Nested(
        PlayerBackpackInventoryItem,
        missing=[PlayerBackpackInventoryItem.from_name("knife")],
    )
    """
    Collection of items that a player can store in their backpack
    """
```

In the above example, we expected the parsed result to be:

```py
[
  ("score", "Total points from killing zombies and finding treasures"),
  ("name", ""),
  ("age", ""),
  ("backpack", "Collection of items that a player can store in their backpack")
]
```

In my attempt below, it is failing to extract the comments properly, giving an output:

```
[
  ('score', 'Total points from killing zombies and finding treasures'), 
  ('name', ''), 
  ('age', ''), 
  ('backpack', '')
]
```

How can the regex expression (or even the entire parsing logic) be fixed to handle the situations present in the example class code?

Thanks

```py
import re

code_block = '''class Player(Schema):
    score = fields.Float()
    """
    Total points from killing zombies and finding treasures
    """

    name = fields.String()
    age = fields.Int()

    backpack = fields.Nested(
        PlayerBackpackInventoryItem,
        missing=[PlayerBackpackInventoryItem.from_name("knife")],
    )
    """
    Collection of items that a player can store in their backpack
    """
'''


def parse_schema_comments(code):
    # Regular expression pattern to match field names and multiline comments
    pattern = r'(\w+)\s*=\s*fields\.\w+\([^\)]*\)(?:\n\s*"""\n(.*?)\n\s*""")?'

    # Find all matches using the pattern
    matches = re.findall(pattern, code, re.DOTALL)

    # Process the matches to format them as required
    result = []
    for match in matches:
        field_name, comment = match
        comment = comment.strip() if comment else ""
        result.append((field_name, comment))

    return result


parsed_comments = parse_schema_comments(code_block)
print(parsed_comments)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might use [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), e.g.:

```py
import ast

code_block = '''class Player(Schema):
    score = fields.Float()
    """
    Total points from killing zombies and finding treasures
    """

    name = fields.String()
    age = fields.Int()

    backpack = fields.Nested(
        PlayerBackpackInventoryItem,
        missing=[PlayerBackpackInventoryItem.from_name("knife")],
    )
    """
    Collection of items that a player can store in their backpack
    """
'''

doc = {}
for x in ast.parse(code_block).body[0].body:
    if isinstance(x, ast.Assign):
        name = x.targets[0].id
        doc[name] = ''
    else:
        doc[name] = x.value.value.strip()
print(list(doc.items()))
```

Result ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVLBitswEIUe_RXCl8iwNXssC3voFgq5lML2FsIykceJiKwxmsmSbOkH9Bt62Uv7Uf2ajhSvN4VSHSyheXrPb978-DWeZEfx-fnnQfq3736_-e6HkZIYYKkqRx0-bAK5vbk1i8XCBWA2nwOcMNl7t8MBmpvK6GJHCRXUewwdtx8DgdimlOq6LvsXEghmJB-FTZ9oMHsfgo9b80TDxiMbiJ0SxC7fSULgQ0KeOcohwnAhcy9JsZMObC8qy5jly_0G3H6EYmEqfkIW7Gyp5nU2dDfhlvERo1A6LQWHqxk0eGYVu139B91mWw_5H229j77HulmfGf5uxQcKAZ14ioZ64_UlG9mBdt2Mhd04iIYl99RHLaFPs4-ZSQOpqo6cGvv6reopmWNGa3LtCInRvsbXtBvqTqvrddnPkXlVVkcsEB3a41V5-F5NbuMU6kXDj61A2qJw5vDdXFb5VYasy4CUawyMN_8EHNtHCAecvqzhjRrSqBmKDZ7FKrgt3bBN05wnchrMlwH9Aw)):

```
[('score', 'Total points from killing zombies and finding treasures'),
 ('name', ''),
 ('age', ''),
 ('backpack', 'Collection of items that a player can store in their backpack')]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 pattern = r'(\w+)\s*=\s*fields\.\w+\(.*?\)\n(?:\s*"""\s*([\s\S]*?)\s*"""\s*)?'
```

updating the pattern results in giving the following output:

```
 [('score', 'Total points from killing zombies and finding treasures'),
 ('name', ''),
 ('age', ''),
 ('backpack', 'Collection of items that a player can store in their backpack')]
```

Comment: The tuple with `"backpack"`  should have a comment instead of being an empty string. Expected tuple to be `("backpack", "Collection of items that a player can store in their backpack")`

Comment: Sorry for the wrong output. I didn't check in the right one. Will fix it.

Comment: Working when tested, thanks!